# Pascal почему во все поля массива вставляется последнее найденное.почему?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

```
program n813;
type 
    aq=array[1..7] of integer;
    cq=array [1..5,1..15] of integer;
    bq=array[1..5] of integer;
var
    n,k,i,j,min:integer;
    a:aq;
    b:bq;
    c:cq;
procedure m1(var aa:aq;n_:integer;var mini:integer);
var i:integer;
begin
randomize;
mini:=aa[1];
for i:=1 to n_ do begin
    if(mini>=aa[i]) then begin mini:=aa[i];end;
    end;
    writeln('min=',mini);
end;
begin
randomize;
    for i:=1 to 5 do begin
        for j:=1 to 15 do begin
            c[i,j]:=random(510)-213;
            writeln('c[',i,',',j,']',c[i,j]);
            a[j]:=c[i,j];
            end;
        n:=j;
        m1(a,n,min);
        b[i]:=min;
        end;
            for k:=1 to 5 do
            writeln('b[',k,']=',b[i]);
    end.
```

Comment: randomize; из m1 уберите.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov
Благодарю
но почему же во все b[i] копируется последнее min?

Comment: `writeln('b[',k,']=',b[i]);` вы уж определитесь **k** или **i**. очевидно вне цикла i будет равно 5, вот вы и получаете одно и то же для любого k.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov 
спасибо за указания ..внимательности никакой у меня(
сделайте ответом комментарий...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. убрать `randomize;` из `m1`. Randomize вызывается один раз, например, при старте программы (до вызовов random) как у вас и сделано, повторные вызовы randomize не нужны
2. при выводе `writeln('b[',k,']=',b[i]);` заменить **i** на **k**.

Еще по мелочи:

- передавать в `m1` ни массив, ни `n` не надо. обращайтесь в `m1` сразу к `a` и цикл до `j`. Глобальные переменные прекрасно видны внутри процедур.
- сделайте из m1 функцию и возвращайте значение не через параметр, а через Result, тогда получится просто `b[i]:=m1`.
- upd. ну и дальше если рефакторить, то и `m1` не нужна, а также и массив `a`. достаточно вычислять минимальное значение в процессе присвоения `с[i,j]`, по окончании заполнения строки, записывать его в `b[i]`.

В общем если поудалять лишнее, программа станет и короче и проще.

Comment: > передавать в m1 ни массив, ни n не надо. обращайтесь в m1 сразу к a и цикл до j. Глобальные переменные прекрасно видны внутри процедур.

А вдруг (чисто гипотетически) понадобится использовать код повторно (для другого массива)? В данном случае не критично, но предположим @Анатолийй будет например писать какую-нибудь функцию сортировки, вы тоже предложите использовать глобальные переменные?

Comment: А вдруг надо будет рассчитывать орбиту Марса после столкновения с метеоритом? Смысл решаемой задачи укладывается в три строчки. И плодить функции на каждый цикл - плохая затея, тем более что данная процедура выполняет лишний цикл. Глобальные переменные уже заведены и процедура является локальной, если б она была в другом неймспейсе (в другом модуле в частности), было бы правильнее пользоваться параметрами. Но вы же не предлагаете, например в каком-нить классе в методах этого класса передавать все поля этого класса как параметры, с целью "а вдруг...".

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, я не программирую с использованием ООП (по крайней мере пока). Я "процедурщик" с уклоном в сторону ФП - предпочитаю, чтобы у функций/процедур было минимум побочных эффектов. Пока что программирование для меня хобби, и мне мой подход только помогал.

> Но вы же не предлагаете, например в каком-нить классе в методах этого класса передавать все поля этого класса как параметры, с целью "а вдруг...".

Не предлагаю, потому что в метод и так неявно передается this, а через него уже можно получить доступ к нужным полям :) (в скомпилированном коде доступ к полям объекта так и происходит)

Comment: ну так в модульном программировании глобальные переменные точно также доступны как если бы доступ шел в классе через this.  
вы правы с точки зрения, что если функция работает с данными, то лучше, глядя с нескольких сторон (читабельность, побочные эффекты и т.д.), использовать параметры, передающие эти данные.  
Но тут другой случай. процедура явно инлайновая, используется только в одном месте и работает она со вспомогательными данными, которые специально для нее зачем-то формируют.